# How to change call volume with AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I have an application for calls. I create track and play sound.

```
AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, sampleRateInHz, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, audioFormat, minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

But when I press the volume buttons, the volume of the "media" changes, not the "call".

Can I make the volume buttons control the "call" volume?

I found a way to change the "call" volume, but I need to do it using the volume buttons on the device.

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 10, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my problem. But this is a trick. Thank **Mayur Panchal** for the idea.

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(streamType, (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) ? -1 : 1, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I tried to use `audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL)`, but it didn't work on all my phones.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Audio Manager setMode in IN_CALL and it works fine for me for my VoIP application.

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);


 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d(THIS_FILE, "Key down : " + keyCode);
 switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:

                // Volume has been adjusted by the user.

                Log.d(THIS_FILE, "onKeyDown: Volume button pressed");
                int action = AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE;
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
                    action = AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER;
                }

                // Detect if ringing
                SipCallSession currentCallInfo = getActiveCallInfo();
                // If not any active call active
                if (currentCallInfo == null && serviceConnected) {
                    break;
                }

                if (service != null) {
                    try {
                        service.adjustVolume(currentCallInfo, action, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        Log.e(THIS_FILE, "Can't adjust volume", e);
                    }
                }
                return true;
}
```

Comment: I try: audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL), but when i click audio button, steel have media volume.

Comment: you have to transfer your audio manager to call service.adjustVolume(currentCallInfo, action, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my baresip voip app:

```
   override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        when (keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP -> {
                am.adjustStreamVolume(volumeControlStream,
                        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
                            AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER else
                            AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE,
                        AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI)
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
    }
```

When call is coming in, I set

```
volumeControlStream = AudioManager.STREAM_RING
```

and when call is established, I have to set

```
volumeControlStream = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC
```

because for some reason setting to `AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL` does not work even when mode is `AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION`.